# What's the difference between "dentro" and "adentro"?

Tags: adverbios, selección-de-palabras

**English:**

How can I tell whether I should be using Dentro vs. Adentro? I've read that they both mean 'inside' and looked at some examples, but I still can't always figure out which one to use. Are there any good rules to learn the difference, or examples that illustrate this difference particularly well? Also, is the word 'en' sometimes used to mean 'inside' as well?

---

**Spanish:**

¿Como puedo saber si debería usar Dentro vs. Adentro? He leído que ambos significan 'inside' y visto algunos ejemplos, pero no siempre tengo claro cual usar. ¿Existen algunas buenas reglas para aprender la diferencia, o ejemplos que ilustren esta diferencia especialmente bien? Además, ¿la palabra 'en' también se usa a veces para decir 'inside'?

Comment: Nice question!!

Comment: Tambien vease un ejemplo given by Javi en [mi pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1220/226)

Answer (score 20):

Both **dentro** and **adentro** mean "inside" but the latter is used with **verbs of movement**. For example:

> 1. Nos fuimos **adentro**. —> (The verb *"ir"* means "to go"; movement);
> 2. El perro está **dentro** del coche. —> (no movement involved).

You can see the official reference here for [dentro](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltConsulta?lema=dentro) and for [adentro](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=adentro).

As it is said in the articles, in some parts of America, sometimes "adentro" is used when "dentro" should have been adopted.

"En" can also be used in the same way as "in" is used in English, so you can use "en" (but "dentro" emphasizes it more)

> El perro está **en** el coche.

Comment: Ah.  Es similar a "dónde" y "adónde", ¿no?

Comment: @Phoenix Sí. Lo mismo pasa con "fuera" y "afuera".

Answer (score 7):

Both are adverbs of location and both can be translated as *inside*, the difference is that *dentro* is used to express *in the interior, inside* and *adentro* goes with verbs indicating movement and it is used to express *towards the interior*. Some examples:

> *Dentro de mi corazón* (inside my heart).
>
> *Lo llevé hacia adentro* (I took it inside).

Comment: Is it safe to say it's the same as the difference between *in/inside* and *into*?

Comment: @Flimzy: I'd say yes at least in the cases I could think of, but I am not a native English speaker, so I wouldn't put my hand in the fire for that "yes".

Comment: Can't you also say "Estoy aquí adentro"?

Comment: @jrdioko: yes; *adentro* sometimes is also used as *en la parte interior* (in the interior), but this use is common in certain regions of Latin America.

Comment: Está mal. Primero que nada, hoy por hoy ambas  se pueden intercambiar en casi todos los contextos. Pero *adentro* ya significa *hacia + dentro*, por lo tanto estás usando la única combinación que está mal: hacia + adentro. Lo correcto es *hacia **dentro***

Answer (score 6):

"Dentro" should only be used in the prepositional phrase (frase prepositiva) "dentro de":

```
La guitarra está dentro de su funda.
(The guitar is inside its case.)
```

On the other hand, "adentro" should only be used as a standalone adverb:

```
La guitarra está adentro.
(The guitar is inside.)
```

In short: "Dentro de <algo>" means "inside of <something>", while "adentro" means simply "inside".

Comment: Streamlined, succinct, easy to use guideline.  +1!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent answers given let me point out that *dentro* can also be used to denote the end of a period of time as seen from present: *llámame dentro de quince minutos.* Which is roughly the same as *llámame en quince minutos*, while there is no such exception for *adentro* which is always location/movement-based.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers: **dentro** implies *inside* in relation to a specific place (stated after the preposition "de" or by context).

> El niño está *dentro de* la casa.
>   Mi estuche está *dentro de* la sala.

At least in Chile, **adentro de** is very uncommon, this ["dentro de"/"adentro de" comparison](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dentro%20de,%20adentro%20de&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=10&smoothing=3) also shows it.

By the way, the rules for dentro/adentro can be used for fuera/afuera.