# ¿Cómo se dice "cheers" en español?

Tags: traducción

¿Qué dicen los españoles cuando juntos levantan la copa de vino solemnemente? ¿Cómo se dice "cheers" en español?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Spain we usually say:

> **Chin chin**

or

> **Salud**

Also if you the people wants to wish somebody or something good luck, then someone suggests **un brindis por...** and the rest answers **por**...:

> **Un brindis por** los novios ... ¡**por** los novios!
>
> **Un brindis por** Juan ... ¡**por** Juan!
>
> **Un brindis por** el coche nuevo... ¡**por** el coche nuevo!

Also in a very informal environment, some people do like a ritual saying:

> **Arriba, abajo, al centro y "pa" adentro**.

moving the glass/cup, raising it when they say "arriba", lowering it when they say "abajo" ,moving it to the center when they say "al centro" and drinking after saying "pa adentro".

Comment: Yo destacaría que lo más usual de todo, que por cierto está correctísimo, es decir Chin chin para que quede realmente claro.

Comment: At least in Mexico "chin chin" is not used instead we say "Salud!"

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en Español existen varias palabras expresas para brindar, palabra que mejor se identifica con "Cheers" es "Chin-Chin". De hecho la propia palabra "Cheers" es una derivación de una casi olvidada expresión y que tiene su origen en una antigua costumbre China.

La locución no es onomatopéyica, sino que proviene de la palabra en Chino mandarín "zin", luego "qing-qing" ó "ging-ging" para avivar el sentido, según la captación idiomática del oído, con el significado de "por favor" y que apenas es ya utilizada en nuestros días. Era el modo que tenía el anfitrión de una reunión a que sus invitados vaciaran sus copas.

Esta costumbre se copió y rápidamente extendió hace unos cuatrocientos años a Europa, importada por los misioneros. Más tarde la expresión fue casi olvidada, volviéndose a poner de moda por una frase que aparecía en una campaña publicitaria de una bebida.

En Inglaterra se decía (tsing tsing), en Francia ( tchin-tchin), en Italia (cin-cin) y España con el mismo sonido (chin-chín).