# ¿Fuera vs. Afuera?

Tags: traducción, gramática, uso-de-palabras

Soy un estudiante que está sacando AP Spanish en mi último año de escuela secundaria. Si no es obvio, el español no es mi primer idioma, y por lo general el nivel de AP es una de las asignaturas más difíciles para mí en el momento.

Mi pregunta es simple, y en el título-- no entiendo totalmente la diferencia entre "fuera" y "afuera" (o "a fuera", porque pienso que he visto esa también) y pensé que este fue el mejor lugar para discutirlo en la manera más adecuada.

Con suerte,
Ken

Comment: Es similar a la diferencia entre *dentro* y *adentro*: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/798/2762

Comment: También, el Diccionario de la R.A.E. (oficial para la lengua española) tiene una buena explicación: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=afuera

Answer (score 1):

Copio el fragmento que hay en Fundéu (asesoradapor la RAE).

> Según señala el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, con verbos de
>   movimiento explícito o implícito los adverbios de lugar fuera y afuera
>   (‘hacia el exterior’) se emplean indistintamente, especialmente en
>   España: *Si quieres pelear, vete afuera/fuera*.
>
> Con verbos de estado y en casos sin verbo, con el significado de ‘en
>   el exterior’, se prefiere en España el uso de fuera: *Pedro está
>   fuera*, *Fuera, en la calle, hace mucho calor*. En el español de
>   América, sin embargo, se emplea también afuera: *Lo que pase afuera no
>   nos interesa*.
>
> Por otra parte, afuera puede ir precedido de las preposiciones de,
>   desde, hacia, hasta, para o por, pero nunca de la preposición a. Así,
>   lo adecuado sería de puertas afuera y no de puertas a afuera.

Si por ti fuera (verbo) usaría siempre fuera, afuera lo solemos usar como se menciona en el tercer apartado del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas.

> Como sustantivo, se usa en plural con el sentido de ‘periferia,
>   alrededores de una población’. Con verbos de estado, el complemento
>   adverbial puede ir precedido indistintamente por las preposiciones en
>   o a: *Vivía en las afueras de Malinalco*.

Enlaces:

- http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/afuerafuera/
- http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=afuera

Comment: ‘Si quieres pelear, vete **fuera**’, no me parece una frase muy idiomática

Answer (score 0):

This issue is explained in the links in the comments. I'm posting this question as a translation of the entry in the RAE regarding ["fuera" vs "afuera"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=afuera).

> Afuera:
>
> 1. Adverb of place that, with verbs of movement, both explicit or implicit, means "to the outside", "outwards", "exiting the place where the speaker is or is referring to": «No, primero acompáñame afuera» (No, first walk/escort/accompany me outside); «Lucas vuelve a mirar afuera» (Lucas looks outside again). **In Spain**, the adverb "fuera" is also frequently used to express an outward moving: «Continúo empujando hasta que salimos fuera» (I keep pushing till we are outside). It is also frequently used even though there's no reference to movement, with the meaning of "outside the place where one is or one is referring to", although such use is more frequent **in Latin America** than it is in Spain. In Latin America, "afuera" is used when normally "fuera" would be used: «Se oyeron sonidos afuera» (We heard noises outisde/Noises were heard outside). It may be preceded by the prepositions *de* (of, from), *desde* (from), *hacia* (towards), *hasta* (until), *para* (for, in order to) or *por* (for, because of), but never the preposition *a*, which is already included in the adverb "afuera" (the correct expression is not "de dentro a fuera" but "de dentro afuera": inside out). **In Spain**, when preceded by a preposition, the form "fuera" is more common.
> 2. **In Latin America**, in a colloquial register, it isn't rare to find "afuera" followed by a complement introduced by "de": «Sacó el balón afuera del campo de juego» (He/she took the ball out of the field). However, this usage is generally frowned upon by learned speakers and the RAE advises to avoid it in formal contexts; in these cases "fuera" is preferred.
> 3. As a noun, the plural is used to mean "the outskirts" ("las afueras"). With verbs of state, the adverbial complement may be introduced by either "en" or "a": «Vivía en las afueras de Malinalco» (He/she lived on the outskirts of Melanco); «Ya casi estamos a las afueras del pueblo» (We are almost on the outskirts of the village).

So basically, "afuera" is used when there's movement implied. Otherwise, use "fuera". Also, there are differences in usage in Latin America vs Spain. Depending on where you are at, you will hear different things.